# Trigger NullPointerException Error Before Update

Tags: trigger, dml, before-trigger

I have a simple Before Update Trigger that I want to run when anything on the `Accounting_Instructions__c` is updated. I am not sure why my trigger is not working. I either receive a `NullPointerException` or the field doesn't update.

I have tried running it as an after trigger and doing DML into a new instance of the object. I have tried looping through a list of the objects to be updated, I have tried to have a nested loop over the Case object (the Status field on Case is what I am trying to update). I have tried a simple field update in a single for loop but get `NullPointerException`. I know that trigger.new is not null, I have system.debugged it and have been returned values.

This is my first trigger so I am sure it is a fundamental oversight but any advice is welcome :)

```
//Requirements: Pull all Account Instruction records, related to the Case I am on, that have a Case status of "Sent To Accounting"
//Pull all Account Instruction records, related to the Case I am on, that have "Accounting Complete" field checked
//Update Status on current Case to 'Complete'
//run this trigger when Accounting Instructions field "Accounting Complete" is updated

trigger CompletedAccountingInstructions on Accounting_Instructions__c (before update) {
    for(Accounting_Instructions__c aic : Trigger.new) {
        //aic.Case__r.Status = 'Open'; this seems like the easiest path but I receive a Null Pointer Exception when I do it this way
    }
    Accounting_Instructions__c[] instructions = [SELECT Id, Accounting_Complete__c, Case__r.Status FROM Accounting_Instructions__c WHERE Case__r.Status = 'Sent To Accounting' AND Accounting_Complete__c = TRUE AND Id IN :Trigger.new];

    for(Accounting_Instructions__c aic : instructions){
        aic.Case__r.Status = 'Open';
    }
}
```

The only thing that I found strange was when I system.debugged the trigger.new or the aic variable, I was returned:

```
    trigger.new:
 (Accounting_Instructions__c:{Id=a1Nc0000002sssssI, OwnerId=0053400sssssQnEtAAK, IsDeleted=false, Name=ACTG-00014, CreatedDate=2017-04-28 19:19:51, CreatedById=00534000009QnsssK, LastModifiedDate=2017-05-01 15:31:58, LastModifiedById=005340000ssssAAK, SystemModstamp=2017-05-01 15:31:58, LastViewedDate=null, LastReferencedDate=null, Case__c=500c000sssssAsAAK, Action__c=Do not rerun;Rerun;Rerun w/ fee, Rerun_ACH_Date__c=2017-04-19 00:00:00, Resume_ACH_Date__c=2017-04-20 00:00:00, Other_Comments__c=Test Comment 2, Amount__c=1.00, Send_to_Accounting__c=false, Accounting_Complete__c=true, Loan_Number__c=null, Legal_Name__c=null, Date_of_Bounce__c=null, Debit_Amount__c=0.00, Returned_Payment_Type__c=null, Duplicate_Comments__c=null, Payment_Type__c=null, **Case_Status__c=Sent to Accounting})**
```

Which has the field `**Case_Status__c**` on the object. This is different then `**Case__r.Status.**` Could this be the issue? I have tried to change the field name but I am rejected as it is not a field on Accounting_Instructions__c.

UPDATES:

With Adrian's update:

```
public with sharing class AccountingInstructionsService
{
   public static void openParentCases(List<Accounting_Instructions__c> records)
   {
      Map<Id, Case> parentCases = new Map<Id, Case>();
        for (Accounting_Instructions__c record : records)
        {
            if(record.Accounting_Complete__c == TRUE) {
                if(record.Case__r.Status == 'Sent to Accounting') {
                    parentCases.put(record.Case__c, new Case(Id = record.Case__c, Status = 'New'));
                }
            }
        }
        parentCases.remove(null);
        List<Case> caseList = parentCases.values();
        update caseList;
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

I took what Adrian gave me and added a little more to be able to search for all of the Accounting_Instructions__c's on the Case. See below result:

```
public with sharing class AccountingInstructionsService
{
    public static void openParentCases(List<Accounting_Instructions__c> records)
    {
       Id caseID;
       Integer i = 0;
       list<Accounting_Instructions__c> aic = [SELECT Accounting_Complete__c, Case__c FROM Accounting_Instructions__c WHERE Id IN :records];
       for(Accounting_Instructions__c a : aic){
           caseID = a.Case__c;
       }
       List<Accounting_Instructions__c> listOfAccountInstrRelatedToCase = [SELECT Id, Accounting_Complete__c, Case__c FROM Accounting_Instructions__c WHERE Case__r.Id = :caseID];
       List<Case> parentCases;
       Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
       for (Accounting_Instructions__c record : listOfAccountInstrRelatedToCase) {
           if(record.Accounting_Complete__c == TRUE){
               caseIds.add(record.Case__c);
               i = i + 1;
           }
           else{
              i = i - 1;
           }
       }
       if(i == listOfAccountInstrRelatedToCase.size()) {
        parentCases = [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds AND Status = 'Sent to Accounting'];
           if(!parentCases.isEmpty()) {
               for (Case parentCase : parentCases) {
                   parentCase.Status = 'Completed';
               }
           }
           update parentCases;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't set *cross object* fields on trigger context records.

When you specify `Case__r` on a record in your `trigger.new` collection, it is null. Hence trying to set its `Status` results in an attempt to de-reference a null variable.

```
for (Accounting_Instructions__c record : trigger.new)
{
    // below is the same as record.Case__r.Status = 'Open'
    Case parentCase = record.Case__r;
    parentCase.Status = 'Open';
    // related record data is not defined on trigger context records
    // hence parentCase is null
}
```

Even if `Case__r` were defined, you cannot update related records in that way. In your code, you need to act on a separate `Case` instance/collection, not `Accounting_Instructions__c`. Implement a **[`Service Layer`](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_patterns_sl)** along these lines:

```
public with sharing class AccountingInstructionsService
{
    public static void openParentCases(List<Accounting_Instructions__c> records)
    {
        Map<Id, Case> parentCases = new Map<Id, Case>();
        for (Accounting_Instructions__c record : records)
        {
            parentCases.put(record.Case__c, new Case(Id=record.Case__c, Status='Open');
        }
        parentCases.remove(null);
        update parentCases.values();
        // add error handling
        // omitted here for brevity
    }
}
```

When updating records, you only need to know the Id. Since in this case the lookup contains that value, you don't need to query for the parent `Case` records. Unless, that is, you want to filter on those records. In that case, you need to query for them.

```
public static void openParentCases(...)
{
    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Accounting_Instructions__c record : records) caseIds.add(record.Case__c);
    
    List<Case> parentCases = [
        SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds
        AND Status = 'Sent to Accounting'
    ];
    for (Case parentCase : parentCases) parentCase.Status = 'Open';
    update parentCases;
}
```

Either way, from your trigger you would just call:

```
AccountingInstructionsService.openParentCases(trigger.new)
```

---

Note that cross object updates should occur in an `after trigger`. See [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm):

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

Comment: Just commenting for extra emphasis that the Null Pointer Exception is due to attempting to work with related data from a trigger context variable. If you're using `Trigger.new`, `Trigger.newMap`, `Trigger.old`, or `Trigger.oldMap`, and your field reference has more than one dot/period/full-stop (like `aic.Case__r.Status`, which has 2), you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: @DerekF Right. I edited my post to try to clarify that a bit.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson this makes sense. I do have a follow up question on the Map.  I am getting error: `DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Map<Id,Case>`. When I dig into it I keep finding that Sets are not available for DML. What would you suggest?

Comment: @Olivia Bah I though I remembered to include the `.values()` call but apparently still managed to leave it out. You use a `Map` to de-duplicate, then get the `List` by calling `.values()` and passing that collection to your `update` call.

Comment: @AdrianLarson no worries, this is working with the `.values()` call. I am still uncertain how to make this recognizable ->`if(record.Case__r.Status == 'Sent to Accounting')`. Should I do something like, query for all Cases related to the current page Id, outside of the loop? and then wrap the conditional around the entire loop?

Comment: @Olivia You have to query for the `Case` records to get that data. It's a bit of a different question...but I have altered my answer in a way that hopefully both answers your new question and preserves context.

Comment: @AdrianLarson thanks this helped a lot, I ended up resolving it and added my final results to the original post

Answer (score 0):

You should query for the relationship object field values. Assuming, Accounting_Instructions__c is parent for your case object, try the following:

```
trigger CompletedAccountingInstructions on Accounting_Instructions__c (before update) {
    List<case> caseList = [select id, status, casenumber from case where accounting_Instructions__r IN:Trigger.new];

    for(case cs:caseList){
    cs.status = 'open';
    }

    /*for(Accounting_Instructions__c aic : Trigger.new) {
        //aic.Case__r.Status = 'Open'; this seems like the easiest path but I receive a Null Pointer Exception when I do it this way
    }*/
    Accounting_Instructions__c[] instructions = [SELECT Id, Accounting_Complete__c, Case__r.Status FROM Accounting_Instructions__c WHERE Case__r.Status = 'Sent To Accounting' AND Accounting_Complete__c = TRUE AND Id IN :Trigger.new];

    for(Accounting_Instructions__c aic : instructions){
        aic.Case__r.Status = 'Open';
    }
}
```

Change the relationship accordingly in the query if its different.

Comment: The OP sure makes it look like `Case` is the parent, not child.

Comment: Yes, the Case is the Parent. So unfortunately I can't query for accounting_Instructions__r .