# Combining lists of different types, including parent fields

Tags: apex, soql, list

I have two lists that I am trying to combine to get one list of pets available for adoption (not really, but it's less boring than reality):

```
List<puppy> puppies = [SELECT Color, Name, Age, PetStores__r.Location, PetStores__r.Section FROM puppy];

List<kitten> kittens = [SELECT Color, Name, Age, PetStores__r.Location, PetStores__r.Section FROM kitten];
```

I'm running through all results in kitten and casting them to the superior puppy category. But I am getting stuck on figuring out how to add the PetStores fields to the puppy list.

```
for (kitten k : kittens){
    Puppy p = new Puppy();
    p.Color = k.Color;
    etc
    p.PetStores__r.Location = k.PetStores__r.Location; //This is where I am getting lost. Is this possible?
    puppies.add(p);
}
```

The above gives me a de-reference a null object error on the noted line. Is there something easy that I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Trigger NullPointerException Error Before Update](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172380/2995)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p.PetStores__r.Location = k.PetStores__r.Location;
```

PetStores__r needs to be populated first:

```
if(p.PetStores__r == null) {
  p.PetStores__r = new PetStore__c();
}
p.PetStores__r.Location = k.PetStores__r.Location;
```

Comment: If the goal is to save to the database, this would never work, right?

Comment: Thank you! This got me exactly what I needed - though I will not be saving anything, per Adrian's question.

Comment: @mplax Glad I could help! As Adrian set, remember you'd have to set the PetStores__c field to the correct PetStore__c Id if you did want to save to the database, but that's about it.